# Can't update list with setState() in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a list of objects that I can display in a ListView. Now I wanted to implement a search feature and only display the search result. When I try to do it using onChanged on TextField(or even Controller) it doesn't work. I tried to debug and he gets the list updated correctly but he doesn't update the Widget. But when I removed the onChanged and added a button and then called the same method that I was calling on onChanged everything worked.
The goal is to update the widget as the user writes in the text field.

I would be happy to get some help

My full code :

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hello_fridge/single_ingredient_icon.dart';
import 'package:string_similarity/string_similarity.dart';
import 'entities/ingredient.dart';

class IngredientsContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  const IngredientsContainer({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _IngredientsContainerState createState() => _IngredientsContainerState();
}

class _IngredientsContainerState extends State<IngredientsContainer> {
  late List<Ingredient> ingredients;
  final searchController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is disposed.
    searchController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void updateResults(String newValue) {
    if (newValue.isEmpty) {
      ingredients = Ingredient.getDummyIngredients();
    } else {
      print("new Value = $newValue");
      ingredients = this.ingredients.where((ing) {
        double similarity =
            StringSimilarity.compareTwoStrings(ing.name, newValue);
        print("$similarity for ${ing.name}");
        return similarity > 0.2;
      }).toList();
      ingredients.forEach((element) {
        print("found ${element.name}");
      });
    }
    setState(() {});
  }

  Widget _searchBar(List<Ingredient> ingredients) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          splashColor: Colors.grey,
          icon: Icon(Icons.restaurant),
          onPressed: null,
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: TextField(
            controller: searchController,
            onChanged: (newValue) {
              updateResults(newValue);
            },
            cursorColor: Colors.black,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.go,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                hintText: "Search..."),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
          child: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.search,
              color: Color(0xff9ccc65),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              updateResults(searchController.text);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    this.ingredients = Ingredient.getDummyIngredients();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Column(children: [
        Expanded(flex: 1, child: _searchBar(this.ingredients)),
        Expanded(flex: 4, child: IngredientsGrid(this.ingredients))
      ]),
    );
  }
}

class IngredientsGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  List<Ingredient> ingredients;

  IngredientsGrid(this.ingredients);

  List<Widget> _buildIngredients() {
    return this.ingredients.map((ing) => SingleIngredientIcon(ing)).toList();
  }

  // const IngredientsGrid({
  //   Key? key,
  // }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    this.ingredients.forEach((ing) => print(ing.name! + ","));
    return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        GridView.count(
            crossAxisCount: 4,
            // physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            // to disable GridView's scrolling
            shrinkWrap: true,
            // You won't see infinite size error
            children: _buildIngredients()),
        // ...... other list children.
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**Moreover,** I keep getting this Warning :
"Changing the content within the composing region may cause the input method to behave strangely, and is therefore discouraged. See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/78827 for more details".

Visiting the linked GitHub page wasn't helpful

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that while you are correctly filtering the list but your `TextController` is not getting assigned any value.

So, no value is getting assigned to your `TextField` as the initial value and hence the list again filters to have the entire list.

To solve this just assign the `TextController` the `newValue` like this.

```
void updateResults(String newValue) {
 if (newValue.isEmpty) {
  ingredients = Ingredient.getDummyIngredients();
 } else {
  print("new Value = $newValue");
  ingredients = this.ingredients.where((ing) {
    double similarity =
        StringSimilarity.compareTwoStrings(ing.name, newValue);
    print("$similarity for ${ing.name}");
    return similarity > 0.2;
  }).toList();
  ingredients.forEach((element) {
    print("found ${element.name}");
  });
}
// change 
    searchController = TextEditingController.fromValue(
      TextEditingValue(
        text: newValue,
      ),
    );

setState(() {});
```

}

If it throws an error then remove final from the variable declaration, like this :

> var searchController = TextEditingController();

Comment: I use the TextEditingController to capture the Textfield value and use it when clicking the search Button and that works fine. What is not working here is this same method when called from the onChanged property of TextField.
I tried adding the chunk of code you gave me, nothing changes except a weird behavior of the cursor(it goes behind each character i write, so strings are written the opposite way)